# Default Value in select menu not appearing starting from select2 v4.0.3

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

While upgrading select2 package from `v4.0.0` to `v4.0.4` I found that the default value of the select menu is not appearing:

[image]

Here is the [jsbin link](http://jsbin.com/lixiqukisu/edit?html,js,output) contains the minified version of my code. You can regenerate the same problem by changing the select2 version from `4.0.0` to `4.0.3 or higher`

It seems like a bug but I am not sure. Am I missing something?

========= Update ===========

@fightinglion Thank you for pointing out my mistake, I was trying something else on jsbin and mistakenly left some part unchanged. Here is the [Jsbin link with correction](http://jsbin.com/buyavuvawa/edit?html,js,output). Sorry for inconvenience.

I'm still facing the same issue.So, attaching the markup generated by select2 v4.0.3 and v4.0.0 [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9Obj.jpg). As far as I understood the default value in select2 is coming from the span with class `select2-selection__rendered`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the problem of select2, but your code has a bug and it is showed up by select2 4.0.3.

See the following picture, the option value you set is not correct. It's because when the link function executes, attr.value is undefined.

[image: bug]